# Turning user ID into name (separate tables) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to display the username of people who i am following, the problem is that during the following process, only the ID of me and the person i'm following is stored.

I've got it to the point where the ID's are displayed but i'd like to show the names hyperlinked. $p_id is the profile ID.

Here's what I've got:

```
$following = mysql_query("SELECT `follower`, `followed` FROM user_follow WHERE follower=$p_id");

I am following: <?php while($apple = mysql_fetch_array($following)){

            echo '<a href="'.$apple['followed'].'">+'.$apple['followed'].'</a> ';
            }?>
```

The usernames are in a different table "users" under the field "username" - I need them to match up with the ID's that are currently displayed, and be displayed.

Comment: The old `mysql_*()` functions are planned for deprecation, and should not be used in new code. Instead, consider moving to a newer API supporting prepared statements such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need is a pair of `JOIN`s (implicitly `INNER JOIN`) against `users`, one to join in the follower and one to join in the followed.

```
SELECT 
  /* Rather than SELECT * you need to be specific about the columns, and
     give them aliases like followed_name since you have 2 tables with the same
     column names in the query */
  ufollower.id AS follower_id,
  ufollower.username AS follower_name,
  ufollowed.id AS followed_id,
  ufollowed.username AS followed_name
FROM
  /* JOIN twice against users, once to get the follower and once to get the followed */
  user_follow 
  /* users aliased as ufollower to get the follower details */
  JOIN users ufollower ON ufollower.id = user_follow.follower
  /* users aliased as ufollowed to get the followed details */
  JOIN users ufollowed ON ufollowed.id = user_follow.followed
WHERE
  user_follow.follower = $p_id
```

In your loop, the names are available in `follower_name, followed_name`.

```
while($apple = mysql_fetch_array($following)){
   // Be sure to wrap the name in htmlspecialchars() to encode characters that could break html.
   // This has the followed id in the href and the followed name in the link text...
   echo '<a href="'.$apple['followed_id'].'">+'.htmlspecialchars($apple['followed_name']) .'</a> ';
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I've just tried the code though and in the 2nd part it says that mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in line (while line)

Comment: @mobile That means your query failed.  Always call `echo mysql_error()` to find out what the error was.

Comment: I put the query code you provided in mysql_error() and i get "Warning: mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in" - I don't see any mention of "username" in the code, do i need to make extra columns?

Comment: @mobile Yes, I thought they were `name` but in fact they are `username`. Change them in the query.

Comment: the error is Unknown column 'user_followed.follower' in 'where clause

Comment: @mobile It's just a typo. Should be `user_follow.follower` since your table is called `user_follow` rather than `user_followed`.

Comment: now showing Unknown column 'user_follower.follower' in 'on clause' :/

Comment: @mobile _exact same typo problem..._

Comment: perfect, seems to work great now, what would be needed to return the followers instead of following?

Comment: @mobile Look at the query - there are `follower_` keys and `followed_` keys in the array.  `follower_name` for example.

Comment: I see, but if i attempt follower_name in another while loop it returns nothing

Comment: You cannot start a new while loop without rewinding the result set. `mysql_data_seek($following, 0)` will rewind back to the beginning.

Comment: Strange, doing that results in showing my user 3 times:

mysql_data_seek($following, 0); while($apple = mysql_fetch_array($following)){   
    echo '<a href="'.$apple['follower_id'].'">+'.htmlspecialchars($apple['follower_name']) .'</a> ';
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to join them together - and because you want to output two id's names independently, you have to double-join the same table twice.

```
SELECT 
    uf.follower, 
    uf.username AS followerUsername, 
    uf.followed, 
    u2.username AS followedUsername 
FROM 
    user_follow AS uf 
INNER JOIN 
    users AS u1 
ON 
    uf.follower = u1.userID
INNER JOIN
    users AS u2
ON
    uf.followed = u2.userID
WHERE
    follower = ?
```

Please use prepared statements or escaping if you create SQL statements! A call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` saves you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Still trying to figure this out, i get a not valid MySQL resource error :(