# Inner Joins, Followed and Following

Tags: php, mysql

I had some help in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886730/turning-user-id-into-name-seperate-tables-in-php) about having an issue with pulling data from 2 tables in MySQL, it appears I needed inner joins.

My Tables:

```
USERS 
  --id (int)
  --username (varchar)

USER_FOLLOW
  -- id (int)
  -- follower (int)
  -- user (int)
  -- subscribed (current_timestamp)
```

The Query, $following =

```
SELECT ufollower.id AS follower_id,
ufollower.username AS follower_name,
ufollowed.id AS user_id,
ufollowed.username AS user_name
FROM
/* JOIN twice against users, once to get the follower and once to get the followed */
user_follow 
/* users aliased as ufollower to get the follower details */
JOIN users ufollower ON ufollower.id = user_follow.follower
/* users aliased as ufollowed to get the followed details */
JOIN users ufollowed ON ufollowed.id = user_follow.user
WHERE
user_follow.user = $p_id
```

`p_id` is the profile ID of the person i'm looking at.

I need to show the usernames of who I'm following and who I've followed. The code I currently have for some reason is showing *me 3 times* instead of the 3 people I'm following:

```
while($apple = mysql_fetch_array($following)){
  echo '<a href="'.$apple['user_name'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($apple['user_name']).'</a> ';
}
```

Sorry for opening another thread on this, I've been staring at it for hours and I can't get my head around it.

Comment: You need to debug what data you have in the query.  `var_dump($apple)` in your loop to see what it contains.  You have limited it in the `WHERE` clause to one user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance it appears that you are displaying the wrong user's name, showing the followed instead of the follower.  Change your PHP code to the following:

```
while($apple = mysql_fetch_array($following)){
  echo '<a href="'.$apple['follower_name'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($apple['follower_name']).'</a> ';
}
```

Note that your query actually is only returning users that are following you, it does not include users that you are following (which would be those with `user_follow.follower = $p_id`).  Of course, for those users, you actually do want to display the `user_name` column...

Comment: perfect, your code worked! and thankyou for the explanation, i'm still a bit lost with this though, which bits would go where for the "following me"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.user,u.username,f.subscribed
FROM user_follow f inner join users u on f.user=u.id
WHERE
f.follower=1
union all
SELECT f.follower,u.username,f.subscribed
FROM user_follow f inner join users u on f.follower=u.id
WHERE
f.user=1;
```

The query shall retrieve person *user=1* are following + person who are following *user=1*

Answer (score -1):

You are doing an inner join on users twice instead of doing an inner join on ufollowed and ufollower:

```
SELECT ufollower.id AS follower_id,
ufollower.username AS follower_name,
ufollowed.id AS user_id,
ufollowed.username AS user_name
FROM
/* JOIN twice against users, once to get the follower and once to get the followed */
user_follow 
/* users aliased as ufollower to get the follower details */
JOIN  ufollower ON ufollower.id = user_follow.follower
/* users aliased as ufollowed to get the followed details */
JOIN ufollowed ON ufollowed.id = user_follow.user
WHERE
user_follow.user = $p_id
```

Comment: In MySQL, `JOIN` implies `INNER JOIN`.